# I have created UIButton method. now I want set corner radius for action button. How can I add this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

This code is not correct. How i can rewrite this code? or any other way to solve this problem.?

```
 - (IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender {
 }
 actionButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
```

---

```
//my original code
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
backGroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
   blurAlertAction.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)blurAlertAction:(UIButton*)sender {

sender.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
BlurViewAlert * addView = [BlurViewAlert new];
[addView bluredView];
[addView setBlurEffectStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
[addView setTitle:@"Set your goal"];
[addView setPlaceholder:@"$"];
addView.onSubmit = ^BOOL(NSString *value){
    NSLog(@"%@",value);
    return YES;
 };

[addView show];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

*Objective-C*

```
- (IBAction)actionButton:(UIButton*)sender {
   sender.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

  // the above line is not working try below line 
  actionButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
}
```

*Swift*

```
func actionButton(sender:UIButton!)
{
sender.layer.cornerRadius = 4

 // the above line is not working try below line 
  actionButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
println("Button is working")
}
```

if you want do this in outside `UIButton` Action do like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

 super.viewDidLoad()

  // then don't write here 
  actionButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4

 }
```

**Choice**

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 backGroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];

}




- (IBAction)blurAlertAction:(UIButton*)sender {

 sender.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;

  }
```

Comment: thank you. This is working, but when i click this button then only, It will happen.

Comment: oh simple , then remove the line in view did load and add the line in your button action

Comment: it works or not , if you need assistance i modify my answer

Comment: can you post your updated code, in here you need corner radius of which button u select  , correct or else u need anything else

Comment: actionButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
actionButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

Try this in ViewDidLoad

Comment: check the **choice** answer and reply me it working or not

Comment: inside ibaction, It working perfectly, but it will happen only when i click that button. 

but, In viewDidLoad, It shows undeclared identifier for method name

Comment: I don't know clearly what u tried , but if you want to show the different categories , this is the way we do , any way my answer is working fine give the upvote for my answer

Comment: @user3352317 : what is the name of the iboutlet of uibutton ?

Comment: @JeneenaJose -- the questioner answered the question , the answer is working fine , the questioner faced the another issue,

Comment: oh! But he didn't accept it, so I thought the code in viewDidLoad is still not working. Sorry!

Comment: see the comment of questioner - inside ibaction, It working perfectly, but it will happen only when i click that button. but, In viewDidLoad, It shows undeclared identifier for method name

Comment: if we know the things we can surely help else part how do we help

Comment: @JeneenaJose -- the questioner will accept or leave or reject on their own willing , we can't force

Answer (score 0):

where is this IBAction defined? If you are trying to set the corner radius for the button on tap, then you probably want to cast that sender to UIButton *, and then set the cornerRadius of the layer of that UIButton instance.

I won't recommend this solution though. I would be able to better answer it, if you could post the whole problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

pass your button in the below method:

**Objective c:**

```
-(void)addRoundedCorner:(UIButton*)viewToRound Radius:(CGFloat)radius{
    CALayer* layer = viewToRound.layer;
    layer.cornerRadius=radius;
    layer.masksToBounds = true;

}
```

call it like this :

```
[self addRoundedCorner:actionBtn Radius:4];
```

**Swift**:

```
func addRoundedCorner(viewToRound:UIButton, radius:CGFloat) {

    var layer:CALayer = viewToRound.layer;
    layer.cornerRadius=radius
    layer.masksToBounds = true
} //F.E.
```